# How to restore postgres 12 dump file into postgres 11.5

Tags: postgresql

dump file generated by `pg_dump` command in postgres 12

command i use in postgres 11.5:

```
pg_restore -h [host] -p 5432 -U postgres -d [db] -1 backup.dump
```

error message:

```
pg_restore: error: could not set default_table_access_method: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "default_table_access_method"
```

Is it possible to restore it? please advice.

Comment: Are there datatypes that prevent doing a copy from the old and to the new?

Comment: Were you able to restore using the workaround that i suggested to you Metalik?

Comment: @AmjadShahzad No your solution did not work. We had to install 11.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

default_table_access_method is not available in pg11. So the workaround is to take a plain dump of source database and remove the following given below entry from your backup.dump file

```
SET default_table_access_method = heap;
```

After that use the below command for restoring the dump on target pg1

Comment: Do you know if this could be integrated into pg_restore as a default?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only `pg_restore` throws an error, `psql` just issues a warning. So you could convert your binary dump to text:

```sh
pg_restore dumpfile.Fc -f- | psql -U user -d database
```

This worked for me on linux.

Comment: It should be `pg_restore -f- dumpfile.Fc  | psql -U user -d database`